# Why Random variable takes values $1$ to $6$ for dice?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, random-variables

It is well known that for a fair dice

$$P(X=1)=P(X=2)=\cdots=P(X=6)=\frac{1}{6}$$

and $$E\left[X\right]=3.5$$

But is it necessary to choose Random variable $X$ takes values $1$ to $6$.

Suppose if i choose $X=5$ for outcome $1$ on dice.

$X=6$ on outcome $2$ of dice and so on

we have

$$E\left[X\right]=7.5$$

But every book gives $E\left[X\right]=3.5$

So is it wrong to choose different real values of random variable?

In general can we choose any real values for Random variable?

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with doing this, other than the fact that in this example it may get confusing.

Comment: I guess the reason is that a normal die comes with $1$ to $6$ on it's faces and that's the value the sides represent.

Comment: You are free to repaint the sides of the die with different numbers. You are also free to define a random variable that doesn't correspond exactly to the number that is shown on the die. These two cases are essentially equivalent, and the result, while technically a die, won't be a standard die.

Comment: @JohnDoe thanks i corrected

Answer (score 2):

You're defining an entirely separate object: a "fair six-sided die", as used nearly everywhere, has the following probability mass function:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline \text{outcome} &1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline\text{probability}&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16\\\hline\end{array}$$

If you had a die that counted from $5$ to $10$, it would look like this:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline \text{outcome} &5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline\text{probability}&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16\\\hline\end{array}$$
And it would be just as valid.

---

I think part of the reason for your confusion is the idea of "outcome $1$". Notice that in the tables above, the outcomes are not ordered in any specific way. I could restate that first table as:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline \text{outcome} &2&1&6&5&4&3\\\hline\text{probability}&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16&\frac16\\\hline\end{array}$$
and it would be just as valid.

Thinking about things in terms of these tables might help you see what makes sense. If you wanted to make a "die" that had possible outcomes $4$, $6$, $8$, and $\pi$, where $4$ and $6$ are twice as likely to show up as $8$ and $\pi$, you can use this same kind of table:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline \text{outcome} &4&6&8&\pi\\\hline\text{probability}&\frac13&\frac13&\frac16&\frac16\\\hline\end{array}$$

Of course, this is a really arbitrary example, just meant to show what kind of random things are valid.

To calculate the expected value of any of these tables, simply add together each outcome multiplied by its probability.

Do these these tables help you make sense of what's going on with normal and less normal dice?

Answer (score 2):

Mean depends on the random variable, not the the event.
if you choose the random variable to be as

```
        X=1 for the outcome of 1
          2 for the outcome of 2
          .
          .
          .
          6 for the outcome of 6
```

Now the Mean would be 
             E[X]=3.5

But if you choose the random variable as

```
        Y=5 for the outcome of 1
          6 for the outcome of 2
          .
          .
          and so on
```

We get the mean as 
            E[Y]=7.5

Finally the Mean depends on the random variable, not on the event.